# Jquery css() not working while trying to rotate an arrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an issue when I try to use css() to rotate my arrow

```
$(function() {
$("#arrowAnim").css("transform:","rotate(300deg)");
});
```

And here's the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/u4wx093a/10/

I can't figure out what's wrong with it,had already search for similar problem but still couldn't solve my issue.Hoping to get some help with it,I'm wondering is it because of the animation?

Comment: Get rid of the `:`

Comment: Oh my! Yes,it works ,sorry for the stupidity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the css function you dont need to use `:` check https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp
Just quit the colon inside the css statement and I'll work properly:

```
$(function() {
    $("#arrowAnim").css("transform","rotate(300deg)");
});
```

see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/u4wx093a/13/